# Как вставить svg код на сайт с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, svg

Я пытаюсь вставить svg на страницу как код. Структура примерно такая

```
<svg fill="..." xmlns="..." viewBox="..." width="..." height="...">
<path d="..."/>
</svg>
```

Я создаю тег svg и пытаюсь создать дочерний элемент path, и он создается, только парный а не одиночный как надо. Пытался делать двумя способами

Первый:

```
path_el = document.createElement('path');
```

Второй:

```
let path_s = '<path d="' + opts.svg.get('d') + '" />'
svg_el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', path_s);
```

Но в обоих случаях элемент автоматически становился парным.

Comment: отдельно - можешь почитать про es6, а именно про шаблонные строки

Comment: @Vadim зачем это?

Comment: А зачем вам именно закрытый? Всё же и так нормально работает

Answer (score 1):

Просто пример

```js
const xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const boxWidth = 64;
const boxHeight = 64;

const svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth / 2 + " " + boxHeight / 2);
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", boxWidth);
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "height", boxHeight);

const circle = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "circle");
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', '50%');
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', '50%');
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '15');
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '1px');
circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'red');

svg.append(circle)

document.body.append(svg);
```